# fixed width sidebar uses more than the 3 defined columns

Tags: css, susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

i have a little problem when I'm using a fixed position element with susy. I know that Elements with a fixed position are sized relative to the viewport rather than the grid. But I don't know how to solve this problem.

I made a pen to show the problem:

http://codepen.io/emjay/pen/vEabNQ

Here is my susy configuration:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutters: 1/4,
    math: fluid,
    output: float,
    gutter-position: after,
    global-box-sizing: border-box,
    debug: (
        image: show-columns,
        output: overlay,
        toggle: top right,
      ),
);
```

And here my Code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p>
        Header
      </p>
      <p>
        Navigation
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>
        This is just a Test Headline to demonstrate this problem
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
  body{
    background-color: black;
  }

  #pageWrapper{
    @include container(1200px left);
  }

  #sidebar{
    @include span(3 of 12 wide);
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 0; // remove gutter on the right side

    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  #content{
    @include span(9 of 12 last);
    background-color: white;
    height: 1300px; //for testing
    color: white;
  }

  h1{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

You'll see that if the windows is larger than 1200px - the sidebar uses more space than the defined 3 columns.

I hope someone knows how to fix that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, size of a fixed element, when percentage, is calculated based on window/document size, not the parent container. While your pageWrapper container can be wide max 1200px, sidebar is always 25.42373% of the document width.

What you need to do is to add media query for screen size minimum of 1200px width and set sidebar size to px - 25.42373% od 1200px:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #sidebar {
    width: 305.08476px; // 1200px * 25.42373%
  }
}
```

See here: http://codepen.io/Fowler/pen/ogMmZP

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I need a "susy" way to fix that problem. I think it's a specific parameter or something like that. :)

Comment: well, you're already overwriting "susy way"by adding max-width to page wrapper... :)